# Deeplinking - Open iOS app from a URL

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

My project is in SWIFT

User receives an email with Change Password link and the link is going to be like this *http://foobar.com/something/reset_token=barfoo*

When user taps on link 'Change Password' it should take him to my iOS app to that particular view controller. I know deeplinking but my URL is going to be like this *http://foobar.com/something/reset_token=barfoo* and not deeplink://

Please help

Comment: I am not so sure about deeplinking. But this is just a guess. 
Why dont you open this link in safari which in-return passes your deeplink:// and opens that the app that you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS9 and newer, you can use [Universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

It allows you to redirect the user to your app from an URL (classic http/s), but he can stay in Safari if he really wants to.

You can found the result in action and a good article about your specific case here:
https://blog.curtisherbert.com/ios-9-universal-links-and-forgotten-passwords/